# Bridge network suddenly stopped working (18.04)

Tags: networking, connection, network-bridge

My Desktop is getting weird. I have Ubuntu 18.04 with a bridge set up (for my gaming VM) and until yesterday all worked fine. Booted up today, no network connectivity. I have no idea where the issue lays, the logs are not very helpful to me. The only thing i changed so far is disable STP for the bridge as that was mentioned in a couple google results I looked at...

```
root@pc-f-linux:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:85:c2:76:de:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:b3:b3:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:b3:b3:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
29: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:85:c2:76:de:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.8.201/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global noprefixroute br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7285:c2ff:fe76:dec5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
root@pc-f-linux:~# cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      match: 
        macaddress: 70:85:c2:76:de:c5
      wakeonlan: true


  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eth0]
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.8.201/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.8.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.8.5]
      dhcp6: false
```

```
root@pc-f-linux:~# brctl show 
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.7085c276dec5   no      eth0
virbr0      8000.525400b3b35e   yes     virbr0-nic
```

demsg -T

```
[So Aug 22 11:09:27 2021] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
[So Aug 22 11:09:27 2021] br0: port 1(eth0) entered blocking state
[So Aug 22 11:09:27 2021] br0: port 1(eth0) entered listening state
[So Aug 22 11:09:43 2021] br0: port 1(eth0) entered learning state
[So Aug 22 11:09:58 2021] br0: port 1(eth0) entered forwarding state
[So Aug 22 11:09:58 2021] br0: topology change detected, propagating
[So Aug 22 11:11:40 2021] device eth0 left promiscuous mode
[So Aug 22 11:11:40 2021] br0: port 1(eth0) entered disabled state
[So Aug 22 11:11:40 2021] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
[So Aug 22 11:11:40 2021] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br0: link is not ready
[So Aug 22 11:11:40 2021] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
[So Aug 22 11:11:40 2021] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br0: link is not ready
[So Aug 22 11:11:40 2021] br0: port 1(eth0) entered blocking state
[So Aug 22 11:11:40 2021] br0: port 1(eth0) entered disabled state
[So Aug 22 11:11:40 2021] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
[So Aug 22 11:11:40 2021] br0: port 1(eth0) entered blocking state
[So Aug 22 11:11:40 2021] br0: port 1(eth0) entered listening state
[So Aug 22 11:11:56 2021] br0: port 1(eth0) entered learning state
[So Aug 22 11:12:11 2021] br0: port 1(eth0) entered forwarding state
[So Aug 22 11:12:11 2021] br0: topology change detected, propagating
```

```
root@pc-f-linux:~# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

```
root@pc-f-linux:~# lspci -vvvs 00:1f.6
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 141
    Region 0: Memory at df400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee00498  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
        AFCap: TP+ FLR+
        AFCtrl: FLR-
        AFStatus: TP-
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it... The computer is connected through powerline adapters to the rest of the network... somehow I never questioned this, because ethtool showed a connection but it must have been something internal. Anyways, unplugging and plugging back in both adapters worked.